# Converting c++ to bash, need to know if a specific variable has bash significance

Tags: bash, c++

I am converting a c++ code to bash for several reasons, one being that I only know bash aside from what I've been learning while doing this conversion!

There's a variable (let's call it "size") that I can't figure out how to understand, but the variable name suggests some importance, so I'm afraid to move on without full understanding.  Here is a simplified code that accounts for every instance of the variable, including in all #include lines that dont have <> around the file (I am assuming those are not package related because I can't find them anywhere in the package).  No #include files mention this variable verbatim...  and this code is all within a span of 40 lines of code and blank lines.

```
for (i=0; blah; i++) {
   int value[3];
   int size;

   .....

   fscanf(inputfile_in, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2], &size);
   for (j=0; blah; j++); {

      .....

      fprintf(outputfile_out, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2], size);

      ......
   }
```

And that's it.  I understand the value array - logically it is simple & the line of the input/output files being read/written are in the exact format "[float#], [float#] , [float#]".

I am lost at the "size" variable.  It SOUNDS important, but I can't figure out where it is being used or why it is needed.

Any idea what this means?  How I should go about interpreting it logically to come up with a bash equivalent for what it happening?  Or chance that it is bum code?  Or that even though it is literally mentioned no-where else, within the structure of c++ it could have meaning in other codes that I'm missing?

Edit: multiple inputs, even if they mimic other comments, are greatly appreciated.  For example, if "size" is an irrelevant/unused variable as suggested by one person below, it would be very helpful for me to know if multiple people agree.  I have to build a rationale for why and how I am changing and ultimately re-writing this program.  =)

Comment: The format doesn't match the number of arguments, and `size` would not be updated by the `fscanf` call shown (nor would it be used in the `fprintf`).  Perhaps your actual program is different.

Comment: Are you *sure* that that's a working C++ program? It looks like a cat got on the keyboard.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey, So, based on what you're saying, do you think it's possible this size variable has no real function?  It is not impossible that this code was just written sub-optimally.  Note that this code is verbatim from my program, other than the var names, and the ..... lines are operations on another input file.  Technically, those operations are not dependent upon the input file this question in related to.

Comment: @Scott, The short answer is yes - I've run it millions of times.  I have never seen this script fail/break for a reason that isn't 100% user related.  I don't think the author is a trade programmer, which could explain why perhaps their cat got to help. =P  The long answer is that I'm not entirely sure, because when I run it about a million times in a loop then run the output through a subsequent script in this package 20K times or so in a loop, I get some errors.  Actually one of the reasons I'm converting the script is to rule out this script as being the source problem...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have, you have a float array [3] `values` and some integer `size`. From what you have provided, there can be nothing drawn about the significance of `size` other than it is a number that follows `value[3]` in the input file. Whether you need it or not, it isn't apparent from your code snippet.

Your code snippet must also be 2 *separate* loops, not *nested* loops, because you can write the `j` index values before you read them with the `i` loop. That part of your code simply doesn't make sense. (a lot will depend on what `blah` is supposed to be)

If the file contains nothing more than 3-floats and i int on each row, then you might as well do:

```
$ cp inputfilename outputfilename
```

If there are more values on each line following `size`, then it is equivalent to:

```
$ awk -F',' '{printf "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %d\n",  $1, $2, $3, $4}' input > output
```

For your conversion, if you were still interested in the equivalent script form of the C code posted, it would be similar to:

```
ifn="$1"    ## input & output file name
ofn="$2"

declare -i size
declare -a value

while IFS=$',\n' read -r value[0], value[1], value[2], size; do
    printf "%s, %s, %s, %d\n" ${value[@]} "$size" >> "$ofn"
done < "$ifn"
```

Note, if you want to write a *new* output file each time, you would need to truncate the output file (e.g. `:> "$ofn"`) before its use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format masks, you can eliminate size from both of these statements:

```
   fscanf(inputfile_in, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2], &size);
   for (j=0; blah; j++); {

      .....

      fprintf(outputfile_out, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2], size);
```

should become

```
   fscanf(inputfile_in, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2]);
   for (j=0; blah; j++); {

      .....

      fprintf(outputfile_out, "%f, %f , %f\n", value, value[1], value[2]);
```

with no ill effects.

Both `fprintf` and `fscanf` take a format mask followed by a varargs list.

> int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);

Thus the meaning of each parameter after the format mask is entirely dependent on the format mask, and since there are only 3 format specifiers, the `&size` and `size` are probably vestigial from an earlier format mask. They are certainly not used by either function.